# PHP MySQL - Fetch same id on two separate table in database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i am trying to fetch this `customer_id` on my table `tbl_customers` and when I get that id i also want to fetch the values of `customer_id` on my second table `tbl_stocks` so that i can bind the data which `tbl_customers` has.

***1st - here is my table `tbl_customers` structure please take a look.***

[image: tbl1]

***2nd - here is my table `tbl_stocks` structure also, please take a look.***
[image]

as you can see what i want is the number of `cutomer_id` on the `tbl_customers` .**THAT** id is bind and will **fetch all the same id and values of row** in `tbl_stocks` which is `customer_id` also, so for this type of query how can i make the sql query statement this problem? so far i have this sql statement but it is not getting the data.

```
 //PSEUDO CODE ONLY IM NOT FAMILIAR WITH THE SYNTAX OF THIS PROBLEM

$sql = SELECT `tbl_customers` FROM `customer_id` = 1 AND SELECT `tbl_stocks` FROM `customer_id` = 1;
```

and so if it is working the final ***OUTPUT*** which i will fetch will be like this for example

[image]

> P.S - I dont need to display it on a textbox or in any form inputs i just need to fetch it using sql query so that i know that program is getting the value of the table thanks !

Comment: It sounds like the SQL keyword you're looking to learn is `JOIN`: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html

Comment: @David , yes sir you are correct i forgot to include the join sql statement on my question. but yes you are right i my instinct is also a join statement. but i am not really familiar with join statement syntax i need to learn it quickly as soon as possible can you help me with the syntax please sir thank you so much

Comment: Like David said, Use join and it’s variants, for example left join.

Comment: @David , and yes sir, i am a beginner in php i am not that in advanced i've just red join statements days ago. and honestly im not that really familiar with syntax so sorry sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `joins`

here is the query you may try.

```
select c.*, s.*
from tbl_customers c
join tbl_stocks s on s.customer_id = c.customer_id
and c.customer_id = 1
```

Further, you should read more about 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html

Here I am going to update answer w.r.t printing values in php page

```
$dbConn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'databaseName');
if(!$dbConn){
    echo "DB Not connected !";
}

$query = "select c.*, s.* from tbl_customers c join tbl_stocks s on s.customer_id = c.customer_id and c.customer_id = 1";
$result= $dbConn->query($query);
while($row = $result->fetch_object()){ 
    echo $row->customer_id;
    echo $row->color;
    // here you may add more columns to print
}
```

Comment: thank you sir, how can I echo or print that and see if it works on my page

Comment: Hi, Answer updated. Please let me know if need more stuff.

Comment: Welcome. Let me know if you need more stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You actually don’t need to query both tables. As the customer id is available in the stocks table, you just need :

```
SELECT
    s.customer_id,
    s.id,
    s.item,
    s.color
FROM tbl_stocks as s
WHERE s.customer_id = ?
```

If you want to query both table, for example to retrieve some other customer information, use a JOIN :

```
SELECT
    c.customer_id,
    s.id,
    s.item,
    s.color
FROM
   tbl_customers as c
   INNER JOIN  tbl_stocks as s on s.customer_id = c.customer_id
WHERE c.customer_id = ?
```

Comment: hello sir! i've got your logic it is correct. but im confused what is about the `c.` and `s.` ? how does that apply on the table? and can you please add on how to print or echo so i can see if it works thank you sir you are such a big help for beginner like me ill read more about join after this works out

Comment: @obitouchiha :  « c » is an alias for table customer, so you can write « c.customer_id » instead of « customer.customer_id ». Same for s, which is an alias for stock table. Aliases just make the request easier to read.

Comment: thanks sir i get the logic of join now. how can i print it sir if my variable there is $sql

Comment: i mean will i print two variables?

Comment: @obitouchiha...  Have a look at [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp) for how to run a sql query using php...

Answer (score 0):

Read about SQL JOINS:

```
SELECT tbl_customers.customer_id,tbl_stocks.* 
FROM tbl_customers 
LEFT JOIN tbl_stocks 
    ON (tbl_customers.customer_id=tbl_stocks.customer_id)
```

Comment: sir thanks how can I echo that and see it on my page? thanks